# Improper integral:$ \int_{-1}^{2} \frac{1}{x}dx$ diverges

Tags: calculus

Show that $ \Large\int_{-1}^{2} \Large\frac{1}{x}$$dx$ diverges

I know it is a simple question about improper integrals, but I am having troubles to argue that this diverges. I know we must look for

$$ \int_{-1}^{2}\frac{dx}{x} = \lim_{t\to0}[\ln|t|]_{-1}^t + \lim_{s \to 0} [\ln|s|]_{s}^2$$

But if we "sum" the limits we will have an indetermination. How to fix it? What is the best way to show this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that this diverges if you write
$$\int_{-1}^2 \frac1x dx = \int_{-1}^0 \frac1x dx + \int_0^2 \frac1x dx \left[ = -\infty + \infty \right]$$
Simply because neither of the integrals are bounded and thus their sum is not well-defined.
However
$$\text{p.v.} \int_{-1}^2 \frac1x dx = \lim_{\epsilon\searrow 0} \int_{-1}^{-\epsilon} \frac1x + \int_\epsilon^2 \frac1x dx = \int_1^2 \frac1x dx = \ln 2$$
Here the "principal value" integral *defines* the integral to be treated as a limit approaching the singularity **with the same "speed" from both sides** which causes the two unbounded parts to cancel each other out. If you were to chose different "speeds" for left and right limits, you would end up with a different value and thus the value depends on the choice of your null-sequence, so it isn't well-defined.

Comment: Well, the answer here is that it diverges.

Comment: @Giiovanna Please read to the end. The concept of principal value integrals is more or less a "workaround" on such problems and my last comment explains why.

Comment: I appreciate your help, thank you. The possibility of choosing "different speeds", as you commented before, permits me to say that it diverges? As you stated before, it Cauchy Principal Value will be $\ln 2$, but I can't say that it converges because the possibility of having different values. Is that correct? Again, thanks for your help

Comment: @Giiovanna Yes, this is correct.

Comment: The convergence of an integral, once formalized, come to say that you can integrate taking out any neighborhood of $0$, provided it is sufficiently small, and the integral outside of it will be near to the actual integral. It's a static thing, no relation with speeds. The integral of $\frac{1}{x}$ does not converge because whatever neighborhood one may choose not to integrate over, one may find some small interval inside of it, where the function's integral is $1$, so the initial guess wasn't near enough. It can never be near enough.

Comment: And an integral can converge to infinity, like $\int_{-1}^{2} |1/x|$.

Comment: @rewritten your "speed" is then chosen by the series of nbhds which you take out. And "convergence" to $\infty$ is bogus when working in $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. It's simply called divergence.

Comment: @AlexR You don't take out a "series" of neighboroods. One of the fallacies of the intuitive understading of this area IMHO is the fact that there is a given "series" or "movement". The actual point is that, given an arbitrary condition that supposedly verifies your hypothesis, you prove that in fact it does not. The movement metaphore stops working very soon, as soon as your space has no countable base for instance.

Comment: @rewritten $\mathbb R$ has a countable base, as you know. The two concepts are eqivalent here, since nbhds, as open, connected sets containing $0$, are intervals $(-\epsilon, \delta)$ with $\epsilon, \delta > 0$ and the value of the integral minus the nbhd depends on the ratio between $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.

Comment: @AlexR I think we both are falling into the philosopher's fallacy. We agree on everything, except for the initial scope of the question... What worries me about the answer is not that it is wrong (it isn't of course), it's that it uses more knowledge than needed. Only the simple "static" concept of convergence is needed here, and it applies unmodified to the extended line, to non-standard real numbers, to any topological space in fact.

Answer (score 1):

$f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$ is not defined in $0$. The point is that you have to sum the left integral and the right integral. The integral limits are pointless (provided they are finite and of opposite sign), as the integral diverges at $0$.

As you correctly state:

$$
\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}dx = \log(1) - \lim_{t\to 0} \log(t) = \infty
$$

Now, suppose that the initial integral converges to a finite number $z$. It means that for any neighborhood $Z$ of $z$ we can find radius $\epsilon$ around $0$ such that, for any open set $B\subset [-1,2]$ such that $0\in B \subset [-\epsilon, \epsilon]$, the integral of $f$ over $[-1,2]-B$ is included in $Z$.

Of course it does not happen, as $B$ always contains a ball around $0$, which in turn contains a closed set $C_n = [e^{-n+1},e^{-n}]$. Removing this set from $B$ will give a new $B'$, outside of which the integral has changed by 1 (contrary to the fact that all integrals were in $Z$).

The same happens if the integral converges to infinity, just use "neighborhoods of infinity" (open sets containing a half-line) instead of neighborhoods of a point.

Comment: Ok, we can see that $ \int _{0}^{2} \frac{dx}{x} = \infty$ as I we noted before. But how about the other part? Isn't it $- \infty$? How we deal with it?

Comment: But you can't add different infinities, can you?

Comment: Yes, it is indeterminated

Comment: The point it that the convergence of the limit, if any, is to be found on arbitrary neighborhoods of $0$. But as you can see, you can remove an arbitrary small neighborood of 0 from the function, and make its integral assume any value. That's why it's indefinite. I'll updte the response with better explanation.

Comment: Ok, that would be great. Thank you very much!